# Finding points with minimum connectivity distance from room

Tags: algorithm, graph

I am implementing an algorithm to find the minimum spanning corridor in a set of rooms. Currently I have the algorithm figured out, I am just trying to implement it. Part of it involves finding so called "special points" of a given room. A "special point" of a rectangle, is a point that has the minimum distance to the farthest point of another rectangle. For example:[image]

The special point for room R1 would be v6 or v7, as both have the same minimum distance to the farthest point in a rectangle other than R1. Likewise the special point for rectangle R8 is v13 or v14, as both have the same minimum distance to the farthest point in a rectangle other than R8. Currently I have the points represented in adjacency lists, with every adjacent point in the list. Moreover I have every room in adjacency lists with each of its boundary points as values. I also have every point with every room that it belongs to.

Currently I am calculating the special point by looking at the distance to the farthest point in every rectangle around that point. Although that is fast, it clearly fails in the following example: 
[image]

As my current implementation will identify V1 and V2 as a tie for the special point of R9, when clearly V2 is the special point (as the distance from V2 to the farthest point in R3 is clearly smaller than the distance from V1 to the farthest point in R2). I could implement it by calculating the distance to the farthest point of all rectangles in the graph and picking the minimum, however I feel that there is a more efficient way of doing so. My thoughts are around some way of sorting the rooms and only checking some rooms, however I still don't have a full algorithm. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't understand your initial example; v6 -> v22 is longer than v7 -> v22, which (assuming the geometry of your illustration shows the distances appropriately) is the farthest point from R1 in another rectangle, no?

Comment: @G.Bach The special point is "the point that has the minimum distance to the farthest point of another rectangle". So for the first example the special point in R1 could either be V6 or V7 as both have the same minimum distance to the farthest point in another rectangle. So the distances calculated are V6->V11 and V7->V10 and those are the same. I hope that clarifies!

Comment: Oh, you mean the minimum farthest distance to a rectangle adjacent to the one you're currently in?

Comment: @G.Bach Not necessarily to an adjacent rectangle. It could be to just any rectangle in the graph. My second picture shows such case.

Comment: Ah yes, I see where I made a mistake.

Comment: You never did clearly explain what `minimum spanning corridor` is. And I would guess it is not the same as `minimum spanning tree` otherwise you would be using some minimum spanning tree algorithm and not asking about this. Anyway, not knowing what you actually is solving makes me unable to help you.

Comment: @Billiska The minimum spanning corridor is the smallest corridor that spans all rooms in the graph from a given origin (reaches all rooms in a graph). The problem itself is NP Complete, so I'm just working on an approximation. This paper further describes the problem www.cs.ucsb.edu/~teo/papers/CorrNPC.pdf‎. Also, one of the author's thesis is on the problem (Gonzalez-Gutierrez). Note that the paper describes 2 variations of it, the one I am working on is described by them as MLC-R. Basically my variation only has rectangles as rooms. I hope this helps!

Comment: @pretobomba That's interesting. So it is **not** equivalent to "converting rooms into nodes and corridors into arcs then perform minimum spanning tree" because the resulting set of corridors has to be connected. Am I getting this correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. The problem is not the same as the minimum spanning tree problem, otherwise I could just run Kruskal's Algorithm on it.

Comment: And just to clarify, currently I am not trying to find an algorithm to find the minimum spanning corridor. I am simply trying to find an efficient way of finding the "Special Points" I described above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In summary, I suggest running Dijkstra's algorithm from all points on your source rectangle simultaneously, with a modified stopping condition. The algorithm keeps track of the current lowest special distance found so far during the search, and doesn't search any further for points that are already further away than the current lowest special distance so far. Some pseudocode below, which uses a dictionary to store target point => (best distance, source point) mappings.

```
enqueue all points on source rectangle
special distance = infinity
while (queue not empty) {
    point = dequeue
    if (distance to point < best distance found to point AND 
        distance to point < special distance) {
        best distance found to point = distance to point
        rect = rectangle of point
        if (all points found in rect) {
            special distance to this rect = max(distances found to this rect)
            if (special distance to this rect < special distance) {
                special distance = special distance to this rect
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

Motivating details below:

You *could* run [Dijkstra's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) to find all points from each source point on the source rectangle to a set of target points. Essentially Dijkstra's algorithm is breadth first search where you only search further from the point at the head of the queue if it meets the condition that it is the shortest path found to that point from your source point.

If you used this condition, you would find the shortest path to all points. You could then compute the longest distance for each target rectangle, and take the minimum of these -- the "special distance" for that source point (and then rerun for every point on the source rectangle and find the lowest special distance). However this is too much work as you will include a lot of points in your search that are far away from your source point and which you don't need to consider.

What you can do is *maintain the current lowest special distance found during the run of the algorithm*, by spotting when you've found all points for a rectangle and updating the current lowest special distance accordingly (it starts off at some high number like `INT_MAX` in C). You then augment the condition for taking points forward by saying that their distance from the source point also has to be less than the current lowest special distance (clearly if the current point is further than the current lowest special distance then you can't do any better by considering paths that lead from it.)

If you are going to be finding special points for every rectangle, you might want to consider running the [Floyd–Warshall algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm), which will compute the shortest distance between every pair of points.

Comment: Your answer does work, however I want to avoid finding distances to all points as that will be on the order O(v^3) and I'll be running my program with upwards of 6000 points, meaning on a 1GHz theoretical machine that'd be about 3 hours.

Comment: @pretobomba I'm not sure I understand what you're saying. My answer doesn't find the distances to _all_ points, as once we've found a complete rectangle, we only look at points that can beat the special distance to that complete rectangle. One issue is that we search from all points on the source rectangle, but the cost of that could be dramatically reduced by carrying over the best special distance found on searching previous points on the source rectangle. In fact we can do better, and simultaneously search _from all points on the source rectangle_ -- I'll amend my post.

Comment: @pretobomba Do you get the O(v^3) because you want to find the special points for each rectangle in the graph? The Floyd–Warshall algorithm, which I'm not v familiar with is O(v^3). With the approach I've discussed in my post, it could be worth prioritizing the queue according to the Euclidian distance from the source rectangle to the rectangle of each point on the queue. Also, if you're searching from all points of a source rectangle simultaneously this should divide the worst cost per rectangle by its number of vertices (this needs thinking about a bit more but hope you see where I'm going).

Answer (score 1):

**This is not a full answer.** It is meant to confirm/formulate the definition of "special points".

Quote from OP:

> A "special point" of a rectangle, is a point that has the minimum
>   distance to the farthest point of another rectangle.

Here is my understanding.
The special point `v*` of room `r` is given by:

[image]

Where

- `V_r` is the set of vertices around room `r`
- `R` is the set of all rooms
- `D(v,v')` is the distance between two given vertices

So, one can see that:

- destination vertex `v'` is chosen to be as far as possible from `v`
- but `v'` has to be inside destination room `r'` which is chosen to minimize the distance

If I'm not too far off with this definition,
then you should be able to brute-force search `v*(r)` with just 3 nested loops.

Of course, you are interested in more efficient method. However, let just make sure I understand "special points" correctly first.